# Animation doesn't start without view update

Tags: iphone, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview

[Sample on GitHub](https://github.com/SoundBlaster/ImageAnimationIssue)

I have a strange problem.

I have Navigation-based app with two UIViewControllers and Curl effect for transition between these.

I add to bar button and add custom action:

```
-(IBAction)pushPage
{
    NSLog(@"push page");
    SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];  
    [secondView release];
}
```

In SecondView I have a button with action:

```
-(IBAction)back
{
    [imageAnimationIssueAppDelegate backPage];
}
```

Method `backPage` in AppDelegate:

```
-(void)backPage
{
    NSLog(@"backPage");
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

PROBLEM:
On the RootView I have `UIImageView` with animation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    animImage.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],                                 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                             nil];
    animImage.animationDuration = 0.5;
    animImage.animationRepeatCount = 0;
}
```

I start it in `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"First view - viewDidAppear");
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [animImage startAnimating];
}
```

I stop it in `viewDidDisapear`:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"First view - viewDidDisappear");
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [animImage stopAnimating];    
}
```

When I back from SecondView animation is stoped! But `[animImage isAnimating]` say `YES`!
It doesn't start witout update screen - you can click to button on the bottom and see it!

**Is it bug?**

Animation works without custom transitions.

When I set `animated:YES` for push or pop view, animation works with custom transitions between views.

**Why?**
Is there simple way to update displaying view to start animation?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have to write

```
 [yellowBatterfly startAnimating];
```

in viewDidLoad method. and change method from

viewDidAppear to viewWillAppear  and

viewDidDisappear to viewWillDisappear.

Hope It will works...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to perform the animations on the view using:

```
[UIView commitAnimations]
```